# (WP) Override WP Plugin Public Function

Tags: wordpress

I want override WP public function in plugin files. I want to place it on my theme functions.php file and don't want to directly edit plugin files because I want this function only applicable when using this theme only.

How can I override this public function?

```
class WP_Job_Manager_Post_Types {
    public function application_details_email( $apply ) {
        get_job_manager_template( 'job-application-email.php', array( 'apply' => $apply ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead try the `job_manager_locate_template` filter:

```
add_filter( 'job_manager_locate_template', 
    function( $template, $template_name, $template_path )
    {

        if( 'job-application-email.php' === $template_name )
        {
             // modify $template;
        }
        return $template;
    }
, 10, 3 );
```

to modify the template path.

Comment: What code that I must put to change url of template? Mean, if job-application-email.php equal to $template_name, it will use new template url: get_template_directory_uri . '/wp-job-manager/job-email.php'

I've try put this code: get_job_manager_template( get_template_directory_uri . '/wp-job-manager/job-email.php', array( 'apply' => $apply ) );

But not working properly. Do you've an idea?

Comment: The locate template must return absolute path, not url, maybe that's part of the problem? So the use of `get_template_directory_uri()` is not ideal here.

Comment: But how to change their template url? Because I'm try change their template url, but it will show text instead replace it.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far? But I think you want the absolute path, not the url. Use something like `get_template_directory()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Never mind, already solved. Thank you very much. Your code is great. :D